# We cannot use 1.toString(), but we can use `let a = 1; a.toString()`; Why?

Tags: javascript, primitive

Is this means assignment in js of primitive makes primitive become object automatically?
`let a = 1` just be transferred to  `let a = new Number(1)`, we know `Number` is a function, and it's prototype has `toString`, this makes sense? Is it right?

Finally, we know the primitive of js is stored in stack memory, but if we can only get object by assignment, so is it means only pointer exists in stack? I am confused. Thanks for your answers if you can help me.

Comment: This is a limitation of the JavaScript syntax. It's not the case in something like Ruby.

Comment: "the primitive of js is stored in stack memory" is not necessarily true. It may not exist at all if it can be optimized away during compilation, or it might never hit the stack if the code is just evaluated as parsed.

Comment: You can always wrap the number in parentheses, if you really want. `(1).toString()`.  The style you want is not allowed just because of parsing ambiguities.

Comment: The token-level syntax interprets `.` as a decimal point. That overrules the meaning of `.` as an object property reference. That's why the enclosing `( )` are needed.

Comment: you can use (1).toString() instead

Comment: i just find the same question you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409939/14404566, give it a check

Comment: So there isn't real primitive data in JS? We can declare `int a = 1;` in Java or C, this is primitive, we cannot use any function of it. But it isn't exist in JS ? If we just declare a `1 or 'string'`, there isn't any variable point it, it's nothing.

Comment: @CodeAlien Primitives just get automatically wrapped when you call a method on them. But this has nothing to do with the question about `1. toString` being invalid syntax.

Comment: @Bergi thx for your answers, I searched, found it is called autoboxing. But I cannot find whether this autoboxing affect the original variable. Like if `let a = 1; a.toString();` whether `a` become` Number(1) `? or after `a.toString()` the Number(1) is just cleared by GC?

Comment: @CodeAlien No, the variable `a` is not affected, autoboxing happens on the value only. The boxed value is pretty ephemeral, it is used only to look up the property (method inherited from the respective prototype) and nothing else (it's not even being passed as `this` to the method, the original primitive value is). In fact it's so short-lived that engines completely optimise it away and never instantiate it in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi Thx for your answers, But  when I tried the code below. If `a` is not affected, how can the code run correctly?
```
let a = 1
a.__proto__.test = () => {
  console.log('test')
}
a.test(); // correct
```

Comment: @CodeAlien Because you're affecting `Number.prototype` there. Not `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not call Number.prototype methods directly from a number in digits form, e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, you have to wrap them in parentheses.

```js
// This doesn't work
console.log(1.toString());
```

```js
// This works
console.log((1).toString());
```